# Write a polynomial of degree $5$ that is divisible by $x^2−2$

Tags: polynomials

I'm stuck with this problem and I can't think of how to do it.

I tried this:

$$x^2(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)$$

Then I did this:

> [image]

Sorry for my English, I'm an Argentinian teenager

Comment: What about $x^3(x^2-2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its $f(x) = (x^2-2)\cdot (ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)$.

Dividing a general 5th degree polynomial into $x^2-2$ is fine.

Comment: As long as $a\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

How about $x^5-2x^3$?  The other three roots, besides $\pm\sqrt2$, are zero.